# StoryboardとUIの紐付けができない

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

現在上の画像のように`Storyboard`に`ScrollView`を三つ配置した状態で、`.h`ファイルにそれぞれの`ScrollView`を紐付けようとしているのですが、`.h`ファイル上に`IBOutlet`を設置することができません。まず、`Custom Class`にクラス名を設定しようとしてもできません。継承しているクラスが問題でしょうか？イマイチ`Storyboard`とクラスの関係がわかっていません。
何が原因で`Storyboard`とUIを紐付けることができないのでしょうか？

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PagerMiddle : UIView

@end
```

------追記------

PagerMiddleクラスの継承を`UIView`から`UIScrollView`に変更すると、`Custom Class`が設定できるようになりました。しかし以前`Storyboard`とUIの紐付けができないままです。

Comment: @kojiaru UIViewControllerのサブクラスのコードと「紐付け」できないということでしょうか？

Comment: ScrollViewのインスタンスを任意のクラスに持たせるなら、"IBAction"ではなくて"IBOutlet"ではないでしょうか? "IBAction"はUIButtonなどが押下された時のイベントを受け取るメソッドになります。UIScrollViewの各種イベントを制御する場合は普通は"UIScrollViewDelegate"を使います。

Comment: Harawoさん
はい、紐付けできません。

Comment: M.I.Aさん
すみません、IBOutletをIBActionと書き間違えていました。本文の方を修正いたしました。

Comment: @kojianu コメント文冒頭を、アットマーク＋ハンドルネームとすると、相手に通知が行きます。（先のコメントで、ハンドルネームを間違えてました。ご容赦）

Comment: @Harawo 了解しました。ありがとうございます。全然大丈夫です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もしかして`Storyboard`から`PagerMiddle`に`IBOutlet`を作成しようとしていませんか？
もしそうであればそれはできません（必要もありません）。

Harawoさんがコメントで

> UIViewControllerのサブクラスのコードと「紐付け」できないということでしょうか？

と確認をしているように`Storyboard`から`IBOutlet`を作成するのは`PagerMiddle`を配置している`UIViewConroller`に対してです。

実際にはこんな感じになります（`ViewController`の上に`CustomScrollView`を配置して`ViewController`に`IBOutlet`で紐付ける）。

[image: IBOutlet]

違うかなと思ったのですが本文中に`UIViewController`に関する記述がなかったので、
念のため記載させていただきました。

的外れだったら申し訳ありません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、もう一度確認してみたいと思います。

Comment: ViewControllerに紐付けするとできました！ようやく意味がわかりました。ありがとうございました。